# How to get documents, where any of the field value matches to any of the listed expressions in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I'am trying to fetch all documents in a collections, where any of the document field can match to any of the listed regular expressions.

*Considering below scenarios.*

User can create documents with different fields names as they wish in a collection.

such as

```
document1 = >{ "_id":1, "card" : 1234 , "status": 4}
document2 => {"_id": ***, "Housenumber" : 356/78 , "value" : null}
------
documentn =>{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e33dd68c9021e453d12"), "searchword" : "win" }
------
```

Field names are not same for all the documents in a collection.

regular expressions can be:"/^(^456$|^win$............etc)/"

I tried to get key dynamically and do find query as mentioned below:

```
          ----------
         table = db.getCollection(coll);        
        DBObject dataKeys = table.findOne();            
        Set<String> keys = dataKeys.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
          String key = iterator.next();             
        regexQuery.put(**key**, new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^((^(([0-9]{4}[-. _]?)$)|"
                + "(^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]...........................0-9]$$").append("$options", "i"));    
            DBCursor cursor = table.find(regexQuery);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
```

I can see key value is coming properly but it is not fetching the matching documents.

I am new to MongoDB and I followed above approach after googling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to regex match on the field names (not the values), then use `$objectToArray` to turn the field names (LHS) into expression-worthy values (RHS):

```
var r = [
     { _id: 1, name: "buzz", addr: "here"}
     ,{ _id: 2, searchword: "win", value: 6}
     ,{ _id: 3, game:0, word: "foo", fruit: "apple", fame: 7}
     ,{ _id: 4, qval:23}  
     ];
db.foo.insert(r);

var rin = [ /ame/, /^val/ ];  // list of regex

db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"}}}
  ,{$unwind: "$x"}
  ,{$match: {"x.k": {$in: rin}}}
                ]);

{ "_id" : 1, "x" : { "k" : "name", "v" : "buzz" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : { "k" : "value", "v" : 6 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : { "k" : "game", "v" : 0 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : { "k" : "fame", "v" : 7 } }
```

Comment: Hi Moschetti, Thank you for prompt reply, Am looking for regex match on the field values not on names. Basically, I need to list down all the documents who has values matching to any of the regular expressions in the list, irrespective of field in which they are present.

Comment: Change the $match on x.k to x.v and you have your solution.   :-)

Comment: Hi Moschetti, I am trying to do it in **Mongo Java**.AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
     new Document("$project", new Document("x", new Document("$objectToArray", "$$CURRENT"))),
     new Document("$unwind", "$x"),
     new Document("$match", new Document("x.k", new Document("$in",new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^(ISBN(-10)?:? )?([-0-9xX ]{13}|[0-9X]{10})$"))))));
but this did not work.